# How did the first transistor work?

Tags: transistors, history

As an EE I learned all about transistors.  Of course these were modern junction transistors for which we have Shockley to thank for developing the physics and the equations.

So I got to thinking about the first transistors and read everything I could find to explain exactly how it worked.  Some of the descriptions are just plain wrong showing a mysterious p-type layer on top of the n-type base.

After my (limited) research I was left with 2 conclusions:

1. The point contact transistor is a mystery which may never be properly understood.
   (Also add to that the point contact diode).
2. Bardeen and Brattain didn't really understand how their device worked either.

None-the-less these guys,  along with Shockley, are rightly giants in the world of semiconductors. Shockley is typically portrayed as sulking because he didn't get his place in history,  but he is single handedly responsible for most everything that followed from that first transistor.

**So question is: How did that first transistor work ?  Where are the emitter and collector p-type regions which are required for "transistor action".**

Comment: The first transistor was a FET, somewhere around 1920's. Sorry that I can't recall more specifics about it.

Comment: @HarryH the first *patented* transistor was a FET in 1925, but it was never produced nor practically demonstrated because the technology wasn't feasible until 1945. The first working transistor was a point contact.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Schottky barrier diodes a "mystery".

Comment: The description in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_transistor#First_working_transistor) seems pretty clear. What else do you need?

Comment: Julianfield patent, 1929.

Comment: @DaveTweed A proper answer would mostly be a copy of Wikipedias many articles...

Comment: Adam,You are correct that schottky diodes are pretty well understood.  Point contact diodes and schottky diodes are not the same.  Are you saying that the C and E contacts are really schottky diodes ?

Comment: David,  thanks for the reference to Wikipedia.  Perhaps you are content with "Max Planck invented QM because he said that energy comes in discrete packets", but it just doesn't do it for me.  For a device which was arguably the most important invention of the 20th century,  there seems to be at best an incomplete description of how it really worked.  But if you have something to add,  I would be most receptive.